# How do I debug for different inputs in R when dput() results are seemingly identical?

Tags: r, dataframe, xts

I've been wrangling data in Python to comply with the [documentation](https://cran.rstudio.org/web/packages/BGVAR/BGVAR.pdf) for the "BGVAR" package in R.

It states that for the `bgvar` class I need to input `Data` as a list of dataframes where each item is named after an entity and every column is named after a variable. The `W` object needs to be a square `NxN` matrix where `N` is the number of entities.

However, when I run this code

```
library("BGVAR")
library("readxl")

Data <- excel_to_list(file = pathtoxlsxwithData)
Wread <- read_excel(path = pathtoxlsxwithW)
W <- as.matrix(Wread)
W
W <- W[,-1]
rownames(W) <- names(Data)
colnames(W) <- names(Data)
storage.mode(W) <- "numeric"

mymodel <- bgvar(Data = Data, W = W)
```

The package throws an error:

```
Error in dimnames(x) <- dn : 
  length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent
```

for some inputs. When I compare the inputs, I cannot tell the difference between them that could be causing the error.

Edit: full script with dputs that reproduces the error as well as its absence:

```
    library("BGVAR")


#this dataset works
data5<- list(CN = structure(c(4.59, 3.24, 3.24, 3.24, 3.24, 3.24, 3.24,
3.24, 3.24, 3.24, 3.24, 3.24, 2.7, 2.7, 2.7, 2.7, 2.7, 2.7, 2.7,
8.06650416308289, 8.34461339283924, 8.5574295507205, 8.8416664184757,
9.17299383383491, 9.43908106690589, 9.69503274624059, 9.97375186158891,
10.3341289752455, 10.6807472746534, 11.3639676234721, 11.7061708798632,
12.1322895358986, 12.5725745334781, 13.091436070924, 13.6849260958503,
14.3713199075819, 15.0355125778046, 15.8370499740831, 98.566272,
97.83291, 98.836061, 99.1672012, 100.1008965, 100.09692045, 100.2640063,
100.9300591, 100.66374, 101.567239, 100.7926206, 99.8662782,
99.4131021, 99.0086457, 99.2423089, 99.4068282, 100.4696215,
100.6094389, 100.8069077), dim = c(19L, 3L), dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("IIR", "MBR", "CPI")), index = structure(c(915148800,
922924800, 930787200, 938736000, 946684800, 954547200, 962409600,
970358400, 978307200, 986083200, 993945600, 1001894400, 1009843200,
1017619200, 1025481600, 1033430400, 1041379200, 1049155200, 1057017600
), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), class = c("xts", "zoo")),
    EU = structure(c(2.9252, 2.5632, 2.4336, 3.0418, 3.5104,
    4.2945, 4.5905, 4.8268, 4.7814, 4.5395, 3.9865, 3.3389, 3.264,
    3.3485, 3.3186, 3.0945, 2.749, 2.2133, 2.0209, 42.0528902876188,
    42.5438693283613, 42.950682509578, 43.5053683124797, 44.6424530671513,
    45.3741172927471, 45.2717683632816, 45.551092571757, 47.3904685378504,
    48.6113984962501, 49.2346889214365, 50.262830868842, 51.3018546794212,
    52.1071597095362, 52.6113170748269, 53.674206164702, 55.014838189854,
    56.4412582156259, 56.8227600227728, 100.90444, 101.021891,
    101.184049, 101.579019, 102.005636, 101.96072, 102.265031,
    102.529457, 102.157986, 102.955839, 102.434531, 102.144632,
    102.56009, 102.112525, 102.106886, 102.300175, 102.31819,
    101.997482, 102.0718), dim = c(19L, 3L), dimnames = list(
        NULL, c("IIR", "MBR", "CPI")), index = structure(c(915148800,
    922924800, 930787200, 938736000, 946684800, 954547200, 962409600,
    970358400, 978307200, 986083200, 993945600, 1001894400, 1009843200,
    1017619200, 1025481600, 1033430400, 1041379200, 1049155200,
    1057017600), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), class = c("xts",
    "zoo")), RU = structure(c(60, 55, 55, 55, 33, 33, 28, 25,
    25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 23, 21, 21, 18, 16, 16, 1.41124672182256,
    1.59329907965375, 1.78179645448887, 1.97570468563864, 2.24040570450153,
    2.52379975867993, 2.85068461482232, 3.21880745853885, 3.48527543523521,
    3.78752721267999, 4.09204522240658, 4.47302782031843, 4.6842626885763,
    4.9668169460222, 5.35451494946906, 5.78343580309854, 6.28162733303322,
    6.8606313442598, 7.51108185634982, 202.6092, 216.8237, 198.22007,
    147.46852, 125.43802, 119.83093, 118.73701, 119.78989, 122.19488,
    124.41, 120.9723, 118.67606, 117.78062, 115.54778, 114.98511,
    115.00793, 114.63042, 114.05352, 113.51224), dim = c(19L,
    3L), dimnames = list(NULL, c("IIR", "MBR", "CPI")), index = structure(c(915148800,
    922924800, 930787200, 938736000, 946684800, 954547200, 962409600,
    970358400, 978307200, 986083200, 993945600, 1001894400, 1009843200,
    1017619200, 1025481600, 1033430400, 1041379200, 1049155200,
    1057017600), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), class = c("xts",
    "zoo")), TR = structure(c(76.32, 76.91, 67.51, 69.97, 39.2,
    43.05, 47.44, 183.2, 81.19, 63, 59.03, 59, 54.73, 48, 46,
    44, 44, 38.23, 30.66, 2.03618691787274, 2.45224466198878,
    2.85152980194772, 3.40383568191502, 4.02924500314335, 4.46950864742143,
    4.88377331905386, 5.1592037849979, 5.96328891188708, 7.56154093609563,
    8.71507793534991, 9.78655006771246, 9.81916170801812, 10.599320649388,
    11.7940455732388, 12.1055918024629, 12.8023795093054, 12.7833858225293,
    12.9848521657004, 164.42184, 163.69998, 164.87749, 166.06177,
    168.82719, 161.65232, 152.65753, 142.31555, 135.63059, 152.29092,
    158.59326, 167.45192, 170.32741, 147.04456, 139.45757, 131.60961,
    126.53236, 125.86128, 121.06997), dim = c(19L, 3L), dimnames = list(
        NULL, c("IIR", "MBR", "CPI")), index = structure(c(915148800,
    922924800, 930787200, 938736000, 946684800, 954547200, 962409600,
    970358400, 978307200, 986083200, 993945600, 1001894400, 1009843200,
    1017619200, 1025481600, 1033430400, 1041379200, 1049155200,
    1057017600), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), class = c("xts",
    "zoo")), US = structure(c(4.81, 4.76, 5.22, 5.3, 5.85, 6.53,
    6.52, 6.4, 5.31, 3.97, 3.07, 1.82, 1.73, 1.75, 1.75, 1.24,
    1.25, 1.22, 1.01, 36.6954197142406, 37.2300769607558, 37.7854895351637,
    38.3004984046071, 38.8976983725056, 39.5507993568616, 40.0165489147731,
    40.6098745547982, 41.6816796871757, 42.7349433933024, 43.694116279649,
    44.6978439365385, 45.4754768882506, 45.8371730689935, 46.7041922994966,
    47.6625349727275, 48.4476398424809, 49.4090266304694, 50.4113705988327,
    101.667696, 102.109359, 102.345981, 102.622484, 103.240178,
    103.329322, 103.508073, 103.4271, 103.393488, 103.377329,
    102.695937, 101.857882, 101.252134, 101.295531, 101.59385,
    102.200075, 102.866779, 102.131603, 102.196383, 264.333333333333,
    253.75, 268.083333333333, 245.75, 255.166666666667, 258.833333333333,
    254, 263.416666666667, 264.333333333333, 262.166666666667,
    275.75, 287.916666666667, 279.416666666667, 283.666666666667,
    364.25, 366.75, 306.583333333333, 301.833333333333, 358.75,
    14.3103989361702, 18.295156626506, 22.3649880668258, 23.826140776699,
    28.2539671361502, 29.3859846547315, 30.5744572748268, 31.2360814249364,
    27.4194019138756, 27.6128148148148, 25.7981572481572, 20.134243902439,
    22.5551535087719, 26.4484615384615, 28.7856198347107, 28.4003557312253,
    33.7766602316602, 28.5684267241379, 30.4364462809917), dim = c(19L,
    5L), dimnames = list(NULL, c("IIR", "MBR", "CPI", "WHT",
    "WTI")), index = structure(c(915148800, 922924800, 930787200,
    938736000, 946684800, 954547200, 962409600, 970358400, 978307200,
    986083200, 993945600, 1001894400, 1009843200, 1017619200,
    1025481600, 1033430400, 1041379200, 1049155200, 1057017600
    ), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), class = c("xts", "zoo"
    )))
W5 <- structure(c(0, 0.1062173, 0.1883998, 0.1033952, 0.445663, 0.4197663,
0, 0.6621655, 0.6400166, 0.5123887, 0.07414336, 0.08450978, 0,
0.14496766, 0.02597733, 0.01588464, 0.07693148, 0.06575524, 0,
0.01597095, 0.4902057, 0.7323414, 0.0836794, 0.1116206, 0), dim = c(5L,
5L), dimnames = list(c("CN", "EU", "RU", "TR", "US"), c("CN",
"EU", "RU", "TR", "US")))
mod5 <- bgvar(Data = data5, W = W5, draws = 10)



#this does not work


data15 <- list(AU = structure(c(82.26542, 76.90665, 81.3056, 13.3278529605016,
13.2675314934202, 14.08287406905, 1.57492049199085, 1.53241145743146,
1.53703787878788, 687779.1, 690014.4, 698007.9, 15.4186513303132,
15.7887207126198, 16.3593905194588, 5.31813882533333, 5.813293651,
6.27242424233333, 21.6562684866715, 22.2824426507816, 22.7961576160219
), dim = c(3L, 7L), dimnames = list(NULL, c("CPI", "EXP", "FXR",
"GDP", "IMP", "LTR", "MBR")), index = structure(c(917740800,
925430400, 933379200), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), class = c("xts",
"zoo")), BR = structure(c(122.0008, 118.3568, 121.3928, 11.4663652061975,
12.0036792773981, 11.5188000894012, 1.76999944444444, 1.71353391812866,
1.85892121212121, 1888531.9, 1896246, 1898302.3, 12.0720366715372,
12.7649682308787, 12.2797300986907, 12.84, 13.48, 14.05, 8.37557145311969,
8.80096626575696, 9.2219031051324), dim = c(3L, 7L), dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("CPI", "EXP", "FXR", "GDP", "IMP", "LTR", "MBR")), index = structure(c(917740800,
925430400, 933379200), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), class = c("xts",
"zoo")), CA = structure(c(95.6446, 96.81783, 98.2313, 56.5147700547161,
58.2006505998734, 60.9462095084936, 1.51118672302738, 1.47301513708514,
1.48561146461905, 1113890.4, 1123208.6, 1140783.2, 51.3699660110776,
53.0084007132572, 54.0430206460317, 5.09697826086957, 5.32331096681097,
5.65603174603175, 31.0106333689699, 31.5177272859839, 31.961391384168
), dim = c(3L, 7L), dimnames = list(NULL, c("CPI", "EXP", "FXR",
"GDP", "IMP", "LTR", "MBR")), index = structure(c(917740800,
925430400, 933379200), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), class = c("xts",
"zoo")), CH = structure(c(94.26778, 97.00242, 95.68923, 19.05200132798,
18.2208427948728, 18.9420780347153, 1.42636358695652, 1.51443228715729,
1.52747196775758, 18.9725459040406, 17.9508938635398, 18.9808202320066,
2.56966666666667, 2.73033333333333, 3.21333333333333, 49.7735085441036,
50.0841532380439, 50.2953552933618), dim = c(3L, 6L), dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("CPI", "EXP", "FXR", "IMP", "LTR", "MBR")), index = structure(c(917740800,
925430400, 933379200), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), class = c("xts",
"zoo")), CN = structure(c(58.0546, 57.23155, 58.45868, 43.5283183955028,
45.7667027202633, 51.369022356663, 8.2787, 8.27856333333333,
8.27743, 37.6837351837686, 41.3163600353252, 41.9422477435453,
4.47663333333333, 4.47663333333333, 4.47663333333333, 8.06650416308289,
8.34461339283924, 8.5574295507205), dim = c(3L, 6L), dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("CPI", "EXP", "FXR", "IMP", "LTR", "MBR")), index = structure(c(917740800,
925430400, 933379200), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), class = c("xts",
"zoo")), EA = structure(c(117.6876, 118.4051, 119.1685, 209.838005174791,
206.344334864423, 214.310007179154, 0.890865035412319, 0.946297424241702,
0.953590795030303, 11401409.4, 11461237.1, 11598799, 204.666656461184,
201.047372041002, 210.300905832237, 3.9924, 4.25743333333333,
5.0507, 42.0528902876188, 42.5438693283613, 42.950682509578), dim = c(3L,
7L), dimnames = list(NULL, c("CPI", "EXP", "FXR", "GDP", "IMP",
"LTR", "MBR")), index = structure(c(917740800, 925430400, 933379200
), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), class = c("xts", "zoo")),
    IL = structure(c(111.1162, 111.1162, 111.1162, 5.09757871712443,
    5.4592682123013, 5.96892630789915, 4.06122011732229, 4.08691197691198,
    4.18112121212121, 163284.8, 168668.4, 169290, 7.10997117053671,
    7.406586771916, 7.9197374186323, 5.21, 5.09333333333333,
    5.21666666666667, 22.8002029860775, 23.805787468422, 24.8224859629471
    ), dim = c(3L, 7L), dimnames = list(NULL, c("CPI", "EXP",
    "FXR", "GDP", "IMP", "LTR", "MBR")), index = structure(c(917740800,
    925430400, 933379200), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), class = c("xts",
    "zoo")), IN = structure(c(70.86469, 69.57063, 70.92097, 8.39952864029184,
    8.44018422538691, 9.52468309974898, 42.4695966666667, 42.8780733333333,
    43.4284866666667, 2268598.5, 2327179, 2356160, 10.5690361503223,
    10.7008370773947, 12.9287236978616, 8.26716666666667, 8.26716666666667,
    8.26716666666667, 8.8035303879122, 9.13320603099139, 9.49252426345693
    ), dim = c(3L, 7L), dimnames = list(NULL, c("CPI", "EXP",
    "FXR", "GDP", "IMP", "LTR", "MBR")), index = structure(c(917740800,
    925430400, 933379200), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), class = c("xts",
    "zoo")), JP = structure(c(185.5802, 205.3497, 183.9057, 98.9686430444595,
    97.2352592101695, 107.217234836789, 116.523421052631, 120.902406078327,
    113.598863636364, 4516739.7, 4533668.7, 4558343.4, 72.7857900351236,
    72.0284287089008, 79.4308397025317, 1.94766666666667, 1.50966666666667,
    1.78, 76.8403418311359, 77.4865630799908, 77.9800907004243
    ), dim = c(3L, 7L), dimnames = list(NULL, c("CPI", "EXP",
    "FXR", "GDP", "IMP", "LTR", "MBR")), index = structure(c(917740800,
    925430400, 933379200), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), class = c("xts",
    "zoo")), KR = structure(c(102.7181, 100.7295, 104.8241, 32.2524721948081,
    34.9171509637589, 36.2037447955411, 1192.05405797101, 1187.39287157287,
    1195.16121212121, 915697.3, 955833.8, 982417.2, 25.8937480394644,
    28.6686974235292, 30.4342735103449, 7.76333333333333, 7.76333333333333,
    7.76333333333333, 27.2030286045815, 27.8539035746815, 28.2525780239985
    ), dim = c(3L, 7L), dimnames = list(NULL, c("CPI", "EXP",
    "FXR", "GDP", "IMP", "LTR", "MBR")), index = structure(c(917740800,
    925430400, 933379200), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), class = c("xts",
    "zoo")), RU = structure(c(61.36739, 64.91503, 84.93548, 15.4860492644414,
    15.9242307983476, 17.0560174296649, 22.8895, 24.4942333333333,
    24.8239, 1742001.7, 1803740.1, 1839252.1, 9.09241637213071,
    9.69047185843195, 9.0749258239904, 98.16, 90.6766666666667,
    75.9933333333334, 1.41124672182256, 1.59329907965375, 1.78179645448887
    ), dim = c(3L, 7L), dimnames = list(NULL, c("CPI", "EXP",
    "FXR", "GDP", "IMP", "LTR", "MBR")), index = structure(c(917740800,
    925430400, 933379200), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), class = c("xts",
    "zoo")), SA = structure(c(10.1824, 11.588, 13.3738666666667,
    3.75, 3.75, 3.75, 1148504.3, 1148504.3, 1148504.3, 7.0808,
    6.9392, 6.92773333333333), dim = 3:4, dimnames = list(NULL,
        c("EXP", "FXR", "GDP", "IMP")), index = structure(c(917740800,
    925430400, 933379200), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), class = c("xts",
    "zoo")), TR = structure(c(67.63757, 70.3793, 72.74276, 6.890286218,
    6.243196527, 6.530444188, 0.34168861884058, 0.395968412337662,
    0.439352015151515, 910591.9, 905458.8, 890187.1, 9.391672566,
    10.05122254, 10.22050927, 2.03618691787274, 2.45224466198878,
    2.85152980194772), dim = c(3L, 6L), dimnames = list(NULL,
        c("CPI", "EXP", "FXR", "GDP", "IMP", "MBR")), index = structure(c(917740800,
    925430400, 933379200), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), class = c("xts",
    "zoo")), UK = structure(c(90.00383, 87.55027, 87.51717, 64.5369466592794,
    63.9992857837613, 68.4235909623759, 0.612205222913043, 0.622407689325758,
    0.624305662727272, 2064137.7, 2072479.5, 2107310.2, 78.0951697878842,
    75.4532585256608, 80.7567020375659, 4.45803333333333, 4.89013333333333,
    5.49806666666667, 35.0503710971087, 35.1602570318163, 35.3874976284418
    ), dim = c(3L, 7L), dimnames = list(NULL, c("CPI", "EXP",
    "FXR", "GDP", "IMP", "LTR", "MBR")), index = structure(c(917740800,
    925430400, 933379200), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), class = c("xts",
    "zoo")), US = structure(c(91.55647, 86.47107, 88.24854, 167.543,
    169.468, 176.035, 12992931.6, 13101422.5, 13274757.9, 237.192,
    249.869, 263.535, 4.98333333333333, 5.54, 5.88333333333333,
    36.6954197142406, 37.2300769607558, 37.7854895351637, 264.333333333333,
    253.75, 268.083333333333, 14.3103989361702, 18.295156626506,
    22.3649880668258), dim = c(3L, 8L), dimnames = list(NULL,
        c("CPI", "EXP", "GDP", "IMP", "LTR", "MBR", "WHT", "WTI"
        )), index = structure(c(917740800, 925430400, 933379200
    ), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), class = c("xts", "zoo"
    )))
W15 <- structure(c(0, 0.007258397, 0.004384407, 0.007124473, 0.046937439,
0.016027547, 0.007413191, 0.039915283, 0.059307258, 0.043306643,
0.00172888, 0.007626772, 0.005573096, 0.013747509, 0.014358853,
0.005843338, 0, 0.006594832, 0.008140664, 0.030819836, 0.023463688,
0.011279637, 0.018533225, 0.012689312, 0.015664346, 0.012533901,
0.015931198, 0.009508997, 0.007760516, 0.025719979, 0.0140926,
0.021594124, 0, 0.011126088, 0.023385409, 0.022573649, 0.011143019,
0.016084155, 0.023795867, 0.016364039, 0.003944071, 0.016867148,
0.008167946, 0.023457056, 0.258992347, 0.010657658, 0.016580201,
0.005491079, 0, 0.011315142, 0.104580939, 0.056779456, 0.057895386,
0.012069034, 0.005796411, 0.028872631, 0.008545085, 0.030086389,
0.037530141, 0.020293891, 0.29541545, 0.21235005, 0.07231354,
0.05097169, 0, 0.03739433, 0.0713611, 0.16024703, 0.28559193,
0.2961008, 0.15012195, 0.19670219, 0.07971904, 0.07721311, 0.1913896,
0.14341162, 0.28888082, 0.06898971, 0.63380519, 0.20780404, 0,
0.34392078, 0.23658324, 0.14555799, 0.13237178, 0.52763098, 0.16813418,
0.49346108, 0.59132537, 0.22004493, 0.003238443, 0.005956027,
0.001707756, 0.004608563, 0.004796915, 0.01827949, 0, 0.0159985,
0.003137514, 0.003756785, 0.007008386, 1e-13, 0.01999201, 0.00527625,
0.01447442, 0.03948706, 0.02485663, 0.00614089, 0.02541879, 0.02859312,
0.01582243, 0.03790926, 0, 0.01375526, 0.02361541, 0.02002204,
0.11864119, 0.02024388, 0.01622535, 0.0231229, 0.19705161, 0.051129,
0.03127153, 0.03016873, 0.18225716, 0.09395666, 0.02823832, 0.04925955,
0, 0.15915297, 0.04544574, 0.16467115, 0.02033042, 0.02784839,
0.0996567, 0.083743087, 0.03629164, 0.013005784, 0.008077664,
0.121588139, 0.023785858, 0.02106277, 0.044982132, 0.091134769,
0, 0.038475866, 0.11478393, 0.024775274, 0.01294248, 0.045654965,
0.002817707, 0.023071514, 0.0024476, 0.011303583, 0.036704451,
0.02975208, 0.016255829, 0.023112611, 0.020704182, 0.025561642,
0, 0.002831056, 0.111771946, 0.016490506, 0.011155943, 0.01022532,
0.01913693, 0.003576951, 0.006503726, 0.02313183, 0.01198395,
1e-12, 0.072994, 0.0415516, 0.04920629, 0.001863715, 0, 0.02051937,
0.007694036, 0.0182116, 0.003622021, 0.00723971, 0.00228576,
0.012022732, 0.007863642, 0.027084105, 0.037849027, 0.012945634,
0.003264646, 0.008246546, 0.05239551, 0.016648586, 0, 0.017044619,
0.006858711, 0.04911127, 0.02892588, 0.02747133, 0.07405134,
0.032128, 0.31747091, 0.06570103, 0.05529758, 0.02602394, 0.02111569,
0.04327837, 0.02200737, 0.06978965, 0, 0.05006517, 0.14128282,
0.25672909, 0.75431882, 0.11667677, 0.24267487, 0.25782437, 0.29108658,
0.19615167, 0.26141669, 0.19974064, 0.06667796, 0.14661014, 0.08606091,
0.14544467, 0), dim = c(15L, 15L), dimnames = list(c("AU", "BR",
"CA", "CH", "CN", "EA", "IL", "IN", "JP", "KR", "RU", "SA", "TR",
"UK", "US"), c("AU", "BR", "CA", "CH", "CN", "EA", "IL", "IN",
"JP", "KR", "RU", "SA", "TR", "UK", "US")))
mod15 <- bgvar(Data = data15, W = W15, draws = 10)
```

How are they different in structure? If there is no difference at all, what else can I do to try to debug besides comparison of dputs? Can it have anything to do with pandas functions that write into Excel spreadsheets?

Comment: can we have a look at `W` as well?

Comment: Or even better, a simple script to produced the error?

Comment: @Derf my bad. Included the dputs for W's for both datasets.  The script is in the post. It uses files instead of dputs because I do not know how to go from a dput to an R object.

Comment: @user2554330, the script is in the post, except I don't know how to substitute reading from files with reading from dputs.

Comment: Just assign the output from `dput()` to a variable.  Which variable are you showing us?  You appear to be reading both `Data` and `Wread` from files.

Comment: Use  `all.equal()`  to learn what's up.   Not to mention the difference between what is printed to the console and what is actually in memory.

Comment: @user2554330 I have added the full script with the dputs assigned to appropriate variables. Had to scrap the original dput code for character limitations though.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I have in fact compared the rownames and the colnames in both Ws to corresponding Data names. I always get TRUE returned but the model only works with one of the datasets all the same.

Comment: Thanks for posting the reproducible code.  I get the same error as you.  Debugging it is a little tricky, because the error is happening in a function called by `bgvar()`.  I'll see if I can spot what is going wrong.

Comment: @user2554330 traceback() output suggests that something goes wrong with the .getWeights function from the [utils.R](https://github.com/mboeck11/BGVAR/blob/master/R/utils.R) part of the package. When I tried to rerun its source code line by line, I first got an error on line 56:`cnames <- names(Data)
  W      <- lapply(W,function(x) x[cnames,cnames])`. Why it happens, I have no idea.

Comment: To me this looks like a  bug in the BGVAR package.  I see you (or someone with a similar error) has posted an issue about it already (https://github.com/mboeck11/BGVAR/issues/19).  When I traced into the function, I got the error at https://github.com/mboeck11/BGVAR/blob/7498d4d3a5b14ca24b391a2637245970dd245036/R/utils.R#L108, where the matrices were the wrong shape, because `endnames` had 20 entries (with lots of repetition).  But choosing unique entries wasn't enough to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a bug in the `BGVAR` package.  It tries to extract the names of variables from strings like

```
[1] "AU.CPI" "AU.EXP" "AU.FXR" "AU.GDP" "AU.IMP" "AU.LTR" "AU.MBR"
[8] "BR.CPI" "BR.EXP" "BR.FXR" "BR.GDP" "BR.IMP" "BR.LTR" "BR.MBR"
...
```

The problem is, it uses a bad method to do it.  So the country name `BR` matches the variable name `MBR`, and then things get really messed up.  (There's also a problem with `TR` matching `LTR`.)

This happens in this line of code:

```
endnames <- unlist(lapply(strsplit(colnames(xglobal)[grepl(cnames[[cc]],colnames(xglobal))],".",fixed=TRUE),
                          function(l)l[2]))
```

from around here: https://github.com/mboeck11/BGVAR/blob/7498d4d3a5b14ca24b391a2637245970dd245036/R/utils.R#L80

It's probably not hard to fix (just require that the country name matches the first part of the string), but there are likely other locations where the same sort of thing happens.

Comment: Thank you for your research but what do you mean by "requiring that the country name matches the first part of the string"? Is "the string" the variable name? Can I circumvent this if I rename the variables so they do not include any region names as substrings?

Comment: I don't know the context.  Everything I know about what's going on is in my answer above.  The problem is that the code looks for country `BR` and matches the string `AU.MBR`.  If they changed the pattern to require `BR` in the first two letters, it wouldn't match.

Comment: I confirm that the replacement suggested in the comments to this post works, courtesy of the answer's author's research.

Comment: This issue seems now be fixed in the new version 2.5.3. See here: https://github.com/mboeck11/BGVAR/issues/19#issuecomment-1845072103